# laravel 8 return Connection to tcp://mail.infomaniak.com:465 Timed Out

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer, laravel-8

I am new to laravel and i am not able to send mail using server. Below given my env file and mail.php file

**.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.infomaniak.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=***.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=***.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**config/mail.php**

```
'smtp' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mail.infomaniak.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'timeout' => null,
    'auth_mode' => null,
]
```

Comment: Most  hosting providers sign emails with SSL so edit your `.env` file to have this `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` also change your port if your ssl required an another port

Comment: also tried it but still it is not working. Give me connection time out error

Comment: after change the env, you need to clear config data `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: everytime clear my cache,config and view file after change in env file

Comment: may be `465` port is blocked from your server, which server you are using?

Comment: Actually i don't know.

Comment: you can check the port block or not as `telnet MAILSERVER 465`(replace MAILSERVER with your mail server (SMTP) which may be something like server.domain.com or mail.yourdomain.com). Press Enter. If that port is blocked, you will receive a connection error.

Comment: From where i am used this command.?

Comment: on your terminal / cmd

Comment: i am not getting any error. Just receive blank black screen of terminal

Comment: Hwy...Found an answer to this, yet ?

Comment: Have you checked why the error message claim that `tcp://` is used? That looks strange to me

Answer (score 6):

In  your env configs change your email encryption to like so: `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` This error is common with `"laravel/framework": "^8.75"` Most since the symphony swift mailer is outdated.

I ran into this bug too after pulling my project from version control and re-installing the packages afresh. The solution above solved my problem and from what I understand about the error is that the swift mailer is trying to open a tcp connection to your server using the smtp port but the connection is only allowed/support `ssl://mail.yourdomain.com` so that's why you get a timeout on that socket stream.

Hope my approach help solve your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `smtp` before your `mail.infomaniak.com`:

```
smtp.mail.infomaniak.com
```